# How to set $cmd overtime in php?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$cmd = 'webscreencapture.exe http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLyG0mUnw4A e:\www\111\1.jpg';
sleep(1);
$cmd = 'webscreencapture.exe http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izUxI-k01CU e:\www\111\1.jpg';
system($cmd);
?>
```

The webscreencapture always run wrong for cycle screenshot one image. How to set a overtime command for $cmd that it can terminated 3 seconds after running the command.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should kill it after 3 seconds:

```
sleep(3);
system('taskkill -im webscreencapture.exe');
```

If you do not have taskkill, or want to use a more robust solution, try `pskill` in the [PsTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) suite.

Edit:
If you want to kill the process inside PHP:

```
$proc = proc_open('webscreencapture.exe ...');
sleep(3);
proc_close($proc);
// or
proc_terminate($proc);
```

You may want to have a look at the [PHP Process Control](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) part of the manual.

Comment: Thanks, is it need a third-party to kill the commomd? not in pure php code?

Comment: Warning: proc_open() expects at least 3 parameters, 1 given in  E:\www\screencut.php on line 291

Comment: $proc = proc_open('webscreencapture.exe http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLyG0mUnw4A e:\www\111\1.jpg'); 
sleep(3); 
proc_close($proc); 
// or 
proc_terminate($proc);

Comment: By the way, set 3 seconds may be not a wise method. Can excuse one time for each $cmd, then cut down? I mean finish screenshot one image for each website, then end the commond.

Comment: I do not know of any PHP `system` kind of function with which you can set time limit for an external executable. So you must either set it with `...proc_open('webscreencapture.exe -timelimit=3 ...'); ...` if the app supports such a parameter, or use a workaround like `sleep`.